# Multiple whereHas Laravel eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel

Please help me to simplify Laravel eloquent query. Is there a way to make it more simple, please suggest because I have a couple of these in my code or suggest me any strategy to make it simpler?

```
if(! empty($has_due_date)) {
        $resourceQuery->whereHas('stages', function ($query) use ($has_due_date) {
            $query->whereHas('groups', function ($query) use ($has_due_date) {
                $query->whereHas('tasks', function ($query) use ($has_due_date){
                    if ($has_duedate == 'yes'){
                        $query->whereNotNull('due_date');
                    }else if($has_duedate == 'no'){
                        $query->whereNull('due_date');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: ... `else` doesn't take conditions

Comment: yes... I just updated to else if

Answer (score 1):

The method [whereNull](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereNull) has a third parameter **not**, so it could be just like this:

```
$resourceQuery->when($has_due_date, function ($query, $hasDueDate) {
    return $query->whereHas('stages.groups.tasks', function ($query) use ($hasDueDate) {
        $query->whereNull('due_date', 'and', $hasDueDate === 'yes');
    });
});
```

Intead of `if` use [conditional clause](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses).

And don't forget you may use "dot" notation to execute a query against a nested relationship, more info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

Comment: Good tip on the extra parameters to `whereNull()`, it would be nice if that were documented. An arrow function can clean things up nicely (no `use` statement required!)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```php
$resourceQuery->when(!empty($has_due_date), function ($q1) use ($has_due_date){
    $q1->whereHas('stages.groups.tasks', function ($q2) use ($has_due_date) {
        if ($has_due_date == 'yes'){
            $q2->whereNotNull('due_date');
        }else{
            $q2->whereNull('due_date');
        }
    });
});
```